# Is there a media server which just receives any rtsp streams and serves them?

Tags: ffmpeg, gstreamer, rtsp

I have some rtmp streams served over nginx-rtmp-module and the number of them will be changed dynamically.

But for the limit of client, I have to serve them in rtsp protocol. Obviously, It's not supported by nginx-rtmp-module. So I plan to run a rtsp server in the same device, and convert the rtmp stream into rtsp stream with ffmpeg, then send the rtsp stream to the rtsp server. So that client could play the stream from the rtsp server.

The trouble is that I could not found a stable server which just receive any rtsp streams and serve them.

[There](http://search.cpan.org/~revmischa/RTSP-Server-0.06/lib/RTSP/Server.pm) is an example that fits all my need but it's a little unstable.

I run it in verbose mode and send stream with:

```
ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost/<name> -codec copy -ar 44100 -ac 1 -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:5545/<name>
```

and play the stream with:

```
gst-launch-0.10 playbin2 uri=rtsp://<server>/<name>
```

The video does not appear and there are some repeated warnning like this:

```
WARNING: from element /GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstRtpVorbisDepay:rtpvorbisdepay0: Could not decode stream.
Additional debug info:
gstrtpvorbisdepay.c(633): gst_rtp_vorbis_depay_process (): /GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstRtpVorbisDepay:rtpvorbisdepay0:
```

When I try:

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=rtsp://<server>/<name>
```

it is stuck and no video appear:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Progress: (open) Opening Stream
Progress: (connect) Connecting to rtsp://211.68.127.12/box
Progress: (open) Retrieving server options
Progress: (open) Retrieving media info
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 0
Progress: (request) SETUP stream 1
Progress: (open) Opened Stream
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sending PLAY request
Progress: (request) Sent PLAY request
```

When I play with:

```
ffplay rtsp://<server>/<name>
```

The video appears but the quality depress me.

Here is the output:

````
```ffplay version 2.6.2 Copyright (c) 2003-2015 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC) 20150304 (prerelease)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-avisynth --enable-avresample --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-shared --enable-swresample --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
  libavutil      54. 20.100 / 54. 20.100
  libavcodec     56. 26.100 / 56. 26.100
  libavformat    56. 25.101 / 56. 25.101
  libavdevice    56.  4.100 / 56.  4.100
  libavfilter     5. 11.102 /  5. 11.102
  libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0
  libswscale      3.  1.101 /  3.  1.101
  libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
  libpostproc    53.  3.100 / 53.  3.100
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 2 packets 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
    Last message repeated 2 times
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] ref 7 overflow
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] error while decoding MB 19 23
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] concealing 615 DC, 615 AC, 615 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] concealing 370 DC, 370 AC, 370 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] ref 4 overflow
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] error while decoding MB 37 23
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] concealing 597 DC, 597 AC, 597 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 3 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] RTP: missed 1 packets  0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] concealing 473 DC, 473 AC, 473 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] concealing 564 DC, 564 AC, 564 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] concealing 605 DC, 605 AC, 605 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] RTP: missed 1 packets  0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 17 packets0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] ref 4 overflow
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] error while decoding MB 27 20
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] concealing 742 DC, 742 AC, 742 MV errors in P frame
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 23 packets0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] out of range intra chroma pred mode at 9 4
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] error while decoding MB 9 4
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] concealing 1480 DC, 1480 AC, 1480 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 7 packets 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] concealing 278 DC, 278 AC, 278 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
    Last message repeated 2 times
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] RTP: missed 2 packets  0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 2 packets 0KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 5 packets
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://211.68.127.12/box':B sq=    0B f=0/0   
  Metadata:
    title           : 
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000033, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p(tv), 720x576 [SAR 1:1 DAR 5:4], 24 fps, 24 tbr, 90k tbn, 48 tbc
    Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 56 kb/s
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] ref 7 overflow vq=  226KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] error while decoding MB 19 23
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] concealing 615 DC, 615 AC, 615 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4264580] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4264580] concealing 370 DC, 370 AC, 370 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f41699a0] ref 4 overflow
[h264 @ 0x7f97f41699a0] error while decoding MB 37 23
[h264 @ 0x7f97f41699a0] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f41699a0] concealing 597 DC, 597 AC, 597 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4264580] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4264580] concealing 473 DC, 473 AC, 473 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4264580] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4264580] concealing 564 DC, 564 AC, 564 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f41699a0] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f41699a0] concealing 605 DC, 605 AC, 605 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4264580] out of range intra chroma pred mode at 9 4  
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4264580] error while decoding MB 9 4
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4264580] concealing 1480 DC, 1480 AC, 1480 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f416a200] ref 4 overflow
[h264 @ 0x7f97f416a200] error while decoding MB 27 20
[h264 @ 0x7f97f416a200] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f416a200] concealing 742 DC, 742 AC, 742 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f416a200] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f416a200] concealing 278 DC, 278 AC, 278 MV errors in P frame
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets53KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] RTP: missed 1 packets 60KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 10 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
    Last message repeated 2 times
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -5 enddists: -4 -4
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -1 -1
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -5 enddists: -1 -1
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 2 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
    Last message repeated 3 times
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -5 -5
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -5 enddists: -4 -4
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -9 enddists: -7 -7
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -5 -5
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -10 enddists: -6 -6
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
    Last message repeated 2 times
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 2 packets
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -9 enddists: -7 -7
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -9 enddists: -6 -6
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -3 -3
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f416a200] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f42630e0] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f416a200] concealing 327 DC, 327 AC, 327 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f42630e0] concealing 327 DC, 327 AC, 327 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] concealing 325 DC, 325 AC, 325 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f41699a0] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f41699a0] concealing 371 DC, 371 AC, 371 MV errors in P frame
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -4 -4 0B f=0/0   
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -5 enddists: -2 -2
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -9 enddists: -7 -7 0B f=0/0   
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -5 enddists: -2 -2
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 2 packets08KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets05KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] ref 3 overflow vq=  207KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] error while decoding MB 20 34
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] concealing 119 DC, 119 AC, 119 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -9 enddists: -2 -2 0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] out of range intra chroma pred mode at 37 23
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] error while decoding MB 37 23
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] concealing 597 DC, 597 AC, 597 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 2 packets
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -2 -2 0B f=0/0   
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -3 -3
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -5 enddists: -4 -4
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 16 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f41699a0] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f41699a0] concealing 435 DC, 435 AC, 435 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] RTP: missed 2 packets211KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -9 enddists: -2 -2
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -5 enddists: -2 -2
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -6 -6
[h264 @ 0x7f97f42630e0] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f42630e0] concealing 519 DC, 519 AC, 519 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] RTP: missed 1 packets158KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 8 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets58KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets55KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets55KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets56KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets66KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f416a200] ref 11 overflowvq=  158KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f416a200] error while decoding MB 13 29
[h264 @ 0x7f97f416a200] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f416a200] concealing 351 DC, 351 AC, 351 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets54KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets61KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 6 packets57KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -2 -2 0B f=0/0   
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -8 enddists: -5 -5
[h264 @ 0x7f97f416a200] out of range intra chroma pred mode at 34 8 
[h264 @ 0x7f97f416a200] error while decoding MB 34 8
[h264 @ 0x7f97f416a200] concealing 1275 DC, 1275 AC, 1275 MV errors in I frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4264580] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4264580] concealing 327 DC, 327 AC, 327 MV errors in P frame
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] RTP: missed 1 packets152KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -5 -5 0B f=0/0   
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -9 enddists: -5 -5 0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f42630e0] P sub_mb_type 12 out of range at 9 26=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f42630e0] error while decoding MB 9 26
[h264 @ 0x7f97f42630e0] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f42630e0] concealing 490 DC, 490 AC, 490 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 3 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 10 packets3KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets29KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets16KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 2 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 2 packets21KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f42630e0] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f42630e0] concealing 513 DC, 513 AC, 513 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets19KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets27KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 2 packets32KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 3 packets
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] RTP: missed 1 packets135KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 2 packets
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -9 enddists: -2 -2
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -5 enddists: -4 -4 0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4264580] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4264580] concealing 230 DC, 230 AC, 230 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 4 packets21KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 3 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 2 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets05KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
    Last message repeated 3 times
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 7 packets16KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] ref 13 overflowvq=  110KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] error while decoding MB 12 33
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] concealing 172 DC, 172 AC, 172 MV errors in P frame
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets12KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
    Last message repeated 2 times
[h264 @ 0x7f97f416a200] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f416a200] concealing 414 DC, 414 AC, 414 MV errors in P frame
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] RTP: missed 1 packets116KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
    Last message repeated 1 times
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets12KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 6 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4000cc0] RTP: missed 1 packets
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] RTP: missed 1 packets126KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] concealing 327 DC, 327 AC, 327 MV errors in P frame
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -1 -1 0B f=0/0   
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -5 enddists: -4 -4
[mp3 @ 0x7f97f4009280] overread, skip -7 enddists: -6 -6
^C[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] ref 7 overflowq=  107KB sq=    0B f=0/0   
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] error while decoding MB 8 24
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] Cannot use next picture in error concealment
[h264 @ 0x7f97f4263d40] concealing 581 DC, 581 AC, 581 MV errors in P frame
````

I'm not sure whether ffmpeg or rtsp-server is the problem, does anyone have some ideas?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

The [FFmpeg documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#rtsp) mentions the [Darwin Streaming Server](http://dss.macosforge.org/) and [Mischa Spiegelmock’s RTSP server](https://github.com/revmischa/rtsp-server) (which you already tried).

Regarding your output you have a lot of **UDP packet loss**: `RTP: missed 6 packets`.

If you're trying to play the RTSP stream on the same local network where your server is located then it's definitely not normal. Try DSS or check network configuration/ports.

If you're attempting on a client over the Internet then UDP packet loss will occur indeed and there's not much you can do. You can try using a **Forward Error Correction (FEC)** mechanism, if you manage to find a server and players that support it. Most devices and software players don't.